# Counting zeros in a factorial(terminal + zeros in between digits)

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

The usual questions involving counting zeros in a factorial asks us to count only the terminal zeros. This question asks to count the zeros that are in between digits, for example, 8! (40320, has a zero between 4 and 3).

Why causes a zero to appear in between two non-zero digits in a factorial?

Comment: I don't think there is any useful structure to the total number of $0$'s.

Comment: Actually when does a zero come in between?And why?If we get to know that we could possibly crack it!